# Is aot (ahead of time) available for mono for android?

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I have found this: 
[Is AOT (ahead of time) compilation available (or planned) in mono for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163502/is-aot-ahead-of-time-compilation-available-or-planned-in-mono-for-android)

However this question is old.

At mono project page it I see ARM is supported for AOT but nothing about Android.

Is AOT available now for Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the commerical version (Monodriod is now Xamarin.Andriod) there is an option to AOT compile your Andriod assemblies just like Xamarin does for iOS (which is a mandatory requirement for Apple store submission):

[Android AOT Compilation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/)

> The AOT Compilation option enables Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation of
>   assemblies. When this option is enabled, Just In Time (JIT) startup
>   overhead is minimized by precompiling assemblies before runtime. The
>   resulting native code is included in the APK along with the uncompiled
>   assemblies. This results in shorter application startup time, but at
>   the expense of slightly larger APK sizes.
>
> Note that the AOT Compilation option is currently a preview feature
>   and requires a Business license or higher. AOT compilation is
>   available only when the project is configured for Release mode, and it
>   is disabled by default.